# Родительный падеж от слова "поц"

Tags: падежи

Как правильно?

1. Как много **поцов** вокруг!
2. Как много **поцев** вокруг!

И почему?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что предложенное слово бранное, не русское по происхождению и не вызывает вопросов по его склонению.

Comment: Что за глупость вы пишите, shampar? Слово как слово. Оно разговорное.

Comment: Это не так. Спросите у родителей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильным является второй вариант, поскольку здесь ударение падает на первый слог. Можете ещё склонение здесь [посмотреть](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%86).

Comment: Так вопрос-то как и есть в том, на какой слог падает ударение в падежной форме. То, что под ударением во флексмях после Ц пишется О, а без ударения Е, это все знают.

Answer (score 0):

По Зализняку ударение в парадигме не является подвижным, поэтому п**о**цев.

Вики-словарь сделан по словарю Зализняка, так что вполне можете проверять там.
https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%86

Answer (score -1):

Как литературного, стало быть и печатного, такого слова нет. Поищите в словарях непечатных слов, их много вокруг.

Comment: На данном ресурсе нет правила, что вопросы должны задаваться сугубо в рамках классических словарей литературного языка.

Comment: Слово это не русское, и не станет русским (своей дряни много, — хоть на экспорт), грязная экзотика. В школе вам это не «впаривают»?

Comment: Школу я, любезнейший, закончил уже очень давно. А ваши рассуждения про грязное и русское/не русское мне не очень интересны, извините. Кроме того в русском викисловаре оно есть. И со склонением по падежам. Вот Тагирикс дал ответ по делу, а вы просто флудом заниматесь. Давайте прекратим, дабы сэкономить время друг другу. Время - деньги.

Comment: Да и не экзотика это. Используется весьма часто. В общем на будущее - не пишите, если сказать нечего.

Comment: «в русском викисловаре оно есть. И со склонением по падежам.» Если  есть, то каких же обоснований ещё надо?

Comment: Да, и об этом человек написал в комментарии здесь. В отличие от вашей болтовни. Еще раз и медленно - не комментируйте, когда вам нечего сказать. Не занимайтесь флудом. Уважайте ресурс и его посетителей. Доходчиво? Внятно? Запомнить и принять к исполнению. Свободен. :)

Comment: Господа, есть предложение не заниматься здесь спорами в подобном ключе. По существу ваших претензий прав Serg Z, нет никаких причин  на лингвистическом ресурсе отказываться от исследования вульгаризмов. А по форме - неправы оба.